# Alternative places to register routes to global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, integration

It's most common practice to register routes in Application_Start event within `global.asax.cs/vb` file. But you need to have access to this file to do so. Fine.

I either don't have or don't want to. I'm trying to integrate Asp.net MVC application into a Sharepoint 2010 site and don't want to create my custom global application class that would also register routes for me and change the Sharepoint's Global.asax file and put a different class definition in it. My application wouldn't be accepted because I would be doing unsupported things to Sharepoint.

I was wondering if it was possible to register routes some place else then? There are two alternatives that first popped into my mind:

1. <strike>**Write an HttpModule** and abuse **application start event** as well. This way I would *inject* application start event code without mangling with global.asax that I can't access. Adding another HttpModule in web.config is something I can do.</strike>

   > **Note:** Application-level events are not accessible in modules. Bummer. They can only access request-level events.
   >
   > **Important:** ... or so I thought. If you check accepted answer it's actually possible to handle application-level start event. Indirectly and reliably it is possible.
2. **Write an HttpModule** and abuse **some other event** like **request start**. Of course I would also have to keep some data somewehere that my routes have already been registered and that registration would happen only the first time round.

**Are there any better ways/places to register routes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Catching Application Start event in an HttpModule is possible

If you check my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370839) you will see this is easily possible. I've done it afterwards and I can assure you it works.

I've also blogged about this *feature*... Twice:

- [Writing a custom `IHttpModule` that handles `Application_OnStart` event](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/08/writing-ihttpmodule-thats-able-to.html)
- [How to correctly use `IHttpModule` to handle `Application_OnStart` event](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html)

Comment: @user960567: you can as well just simply write your own class that inherits from the `HttpApplication` (or other inherited class if something else is used) and change the first line in Global.asax file. There are several possibilities of course. But application is much better encapsulated if it has it's own handler that does it all at app start.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this article will be useful to you

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx

You could use an HTTP module to set the routes on the RouteTable.Routes RouteCollection object.