# Advanced: How many times does HttpModule Init() method get called during application's life?

Tags: asp.net, events, httpmodule

Web application initialization is as follows:

1. As we know when IIS receives the first request for a particular Asp.net application resource, IIS creates an instance of a `HttpApplication` (defined in `global.asax` codebehind).
2. When this new instance is created it's initialization happens that also checks all configured HTTP modules.
3. All modules are then instantiated and put in the application's `Modules` collection (of type `HttpModuleCollection`)
4. modules are looped through and their `Init()` method is called (when they register for request events)

As far as I understand it the above scenario happens when a web application is started/initialized (hence application start event).

### What happens with modules?

Are they (re)instatiated on each request or reused from the `Modules` property on each consecutive request while the web application is alive? As I understand IIS and Asp.net they are reused through the whole life of a web application.

If they are reused, can we assume that their `Init()` method is actually a pseudo event handler for application start event? The thing is we can't attach to application level events within http modules. But if they are being reused we could use `Init()` as application start event and do whatever we'd put in `global.asax` instead.

### Question

Can we assume that module's `Init()` method is called **only** on application start event? Could we use this assumption to i.e. register routes for applications whose `global.asax` codebehind we can't change? `web.config` is usually accessible and we can change it the way we want.
**Would this actually work?**

### Additional info

We can check `HttpApplication` code and check its `InitModulesCommon()` method. This one actually calls `Init()` of each registered HTTP module. What is more interesting is that this method is only used by `InitIntegratedModules()` and `InitModules()` methods. Which are both used **only** in `HttpApplication.InitInternal()` method. This is the basis of my assumptions, but I would like to know whether someone has abused `IHttpModule.Init()` for application start event.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### `Init()` is called only once (per `HttpApplication` instance)

After I tested this the inner workings of `IHttpModule` initialization are as follows:

1. Every `IHttpModule` is initialized at web application start by instatiating and a call to `Init()` method
2. `HttpApplication` stores all module instances in its `Modules` property
3. Modules are then reused for the whole life of an `HttpApplication` and are not discarded/reinitialized as long as the application is alive

### So the best outcome is

You can't attach an `IHttpModule` to application level events, but **you can use its `Init()` method as pseudo application start event delegate**. Inside it you can execute any code that you'd usually put inside `Application_Start` delegate in your `Global.asax`.

You can also read detailed information about it in my [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/08/writing-ihttpmodule-thats-able-to.html).

### But be careful in real-life web server environment

But IIS uses something called *application pools*. And each pool can have an arbitrary number of `HttpApplication` instances. Yes multiple. Application starting creates all these instances. Every one of them initializes their own list of modules but only the first one executes the `Application_OnStart` event handler.

So whenever your module modifies some common shared resource, you should take extra measures to indicate that the first module has done that and others won't do it again. Read an [additional blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html) about it that will show you how and when to use thread locking with your module to make it actually act as an `Application_OnStart` event handler. BTW: It's also possible to handle `Application_OnEnd` event if you need to. ;)

### Detailed blog post links

1. [Writing a custom IHttpModule that handles Application_OnStart event](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/08/writing-ihttpmodule-thats-able-to.html)
2. [How to correctly use IHttpModule to handle Application_OnStart event](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html)

Comment: @MatteS: Misleading in what way? It's perfectly correct, because `Init` is called only once per every `HttpApplication` instance. When one reads through the whole answer (as they should) then they understand how to approach their own problem.

Comment: I am not sure why but the solution you have provided in your blog does not work for me, I receive the error below:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetEventCount(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent) +30
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +408

If I remove the "applicationStarted" variable from the function logic, the website loads fine. 

I am currently using IIS 8.5, .NET 4.5.1 and Integrated pipelines.

Would you have any idea why? Thank you

Comment: @RobertKoritnik do you know if these happen in one go: "instatiating and a call to Init()"? i.e. I am mostly wondering if the module instance is created *after* the application instance.

Answer (score 3):

Application_Start is only run once for the lifetime of your application.

[IHttpModule.Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.init.aspx) is run for each instance of HttpApplication, before request processing begins.  See the [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx).  Init is where you can register events used to process the request.

An instance of HttpApplication can be reused for multiple requests.  ASP.Net pools HttpApplication objects, so the Init will be called once for every new instance of HttpApplication

Comment: The link you provided doesn't say when `Init()` gets called. And based on `HttpApplication`'s code I've examined it doesn't look that modules would be reinstantiated for each request. This is a very basic example of a module that you provided that doesn't give any insight in the actual execution pipeline.

Comment: Check my additional info. It will give you a better insight into this *issue*.

Comment: Exactly! So `Init()` method of a `HttpModule` can be thought of an application start event then. Just as I anticipated. I don't think developers actually realize that or think of it when developing apps. Still it's impossible to get to Session events within `HttpModule`.

Comment: Init does act as an application start event. It would be better to say as an Application init event. Only the first instance also executes `Application_OnStart`. But that can as well be done by a module. You have to use this whenever your module modifies common shared resource. Read all the details in my blog post. http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html