# Create Global.asax from codebehind

Tags: .net, global-asax

Is it possible to create my own `Global.asax` from codebehind?

I want to be able to edit `void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` without the `Global.asax` file

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I'll bite -- why *don't* you want a Global.asax?

Comment: this question/answer might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342158/alternative-places-to-register-routes-to-global-asax

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you cannot programatically declare the `HttpApplication` class represented by `Global.asax`. `Global.asax` represents the `HttpApplication` itself, and so it is technically already created (whether you create a `Global.asax` yourself or not). You can use an `HttpModule` to achieve your objective.